# how to update classes for update roll up 18

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have to prepare the project for crm 2011's Update RollUp 18. From what I understand, from now onward the Micrososft.CRM.SDK dll is not supported anymore, thus I have removed it from my project. As one would expect, a lot of "*could not be found*" errors appeared because of the removal. For the code bellow, I have ".. Property could not be found.." and "..StringProperty could not be found .." .

```
   public class ExtMergeName : ExtPropertyBase, ICrmString
    {
        public Property GetValue()
        {
            return CrmStringObject;
        }

        public StringProperty CrmStringObject
        {
            get
            {
                return (StringProperty)ReturnStringProperty();
            }
        }
```

What can I replace them with?

Comment: you are updating from CRM 4.0?

Comment: your code is from CRM 4.0. You need to use microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll from CRM 2011 SDK and update your code to be compatible with CRM 2011

Comment: What is the function meant to do? Then we can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing a snippet of Dynamics CRM 4.0 code. This is supported in Dynamics CRM 2011, up to the most recent Rollup Update. Support for CRM 4.0 is removed in Dynamics CRM 2013.

When your goal is to upgrade to CRM 2011 only, you can keep your VS projects as is, i.e. referencing assembly `microsoft.crm.sdk.dll`.

When you are planning to continue upgrading to CRM 2013 or CRM 2015, you need to rewrite your CRM 4.0 code. (Plugins, workflow activities, Javascript, external components accessing the CRM end points.)

More information about the programming model of Dynamics CRM 2011 and how to upgrade from CRM 4.0 can be found on MSDN:

[Introduction to Programming Models for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327971(v=crm.5).aspx)

[Summary of Changes Between Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309341(v=crm.5).aspx)

Comment: ok, but supposedly I want to upgrade to 2013, what do I change the Property class to?

Comment: The `Property` class is the base class for attributes belonging to the `DynamicEntity`. In CRM 2011 this - and other `BusinessEntity` classes - are replaced by the `Entity` class. You can find more information on MSDN. I added links to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 2011 and newer versions the microsoft.crm.sdk.proxy.dll is used, along with microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll.  If you're not already using proper version of the CRM 2011 SDK, you can get that here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004.  If you're trying to use the strongly typed entity classes in custom code, you can generate a correct version of that using the crmsvcutil.exe that comes with the SDK.  If that's not exactly what you're looking for, then please provide additional details so I can better understand what you're trying to do.